# javascript toMoney not working correctly

Tags: javascript

hello I have this function

```
ToMoney: function (value, addSign) {
    var res = "";
    if (addSign)
        res = "$";
    var num = value.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");

    res = res + num;
    return res;
}


pr = 95
g2 = 45
wk= 28

$("#grw2").text("$" + Utils.ToMoney(((pr / 60) * g2) / 2));
$("#grs2").text("$" + Utils.ToMoney(((pr / 60) * g2) / 2) * wk);
```

when I run this I get:

```
grw2= $35.63
grps2= $997.6400000000001
```

can't seem to figure why even though I am using ToMoney the res is till showing all decimals.

Also if I use g2=44 instead of 45 then all works correctly, what am I missing?

Comment: Why did you tag this as C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just misplaced parens:

In both of your calls to toMoney below, the highlighted code is what's being passed:

$("#grw2").text("$" + Utils.ToMoney(`((pr / 60) * g2) / 2)`);

$("#grs2").text("$" + Utils.ToMoney(`((pr / 60) * g2) / 2)` * wk);

**Note that in the second call the `* wk` is being done on the return value from toMoney and that is why you got a decimal value that was off from my calculations.**

The correction is to make sure that the entire calculation is passed into toMoney, so an extra set of parens is needed:

```js
function toMoney(value, addSign) {
    var res = "";
    if (addSign)
        res = "$";
    var num = value.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");

    return res + num;
}


var pr = 95;
var g2 = 45;
var wk= 28;

$("#grw2").text("$" + toMoney(((pr / 60) * g2) / 2));
$("#grs2").text("$" + toMoney((((pr / 60) * g2) / 2) * wk));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="grw2"></div>
<div id="grs2"></div>
```

Comment: my issue is with the result using the example above 35.63 * 28 = 997.64 not 997.50

Comment: First you had: `(((pr / 60) * g2) / 2) * wk`, which reduces to: `(((95 / 60) * 45) / 2) * 28`, which reduces to: `(((1.583333333333333) * 45) / 2) * 28`, which reduces to: `((71.25) / 2) * 28`, which reduces to: `(35.625) * 28`, which results in: `997.50`

Comment: See my updated answer as to why your anwser was off.

Comment: the problem is that if we do the calculation manually it only works correctly one way: 997.50/28=35.625 or 35.63 <-- this is correct BUT 35.63 *28 = 997.64 so it just doesn't add up. how to make sure its the same answer going both ways...

Comment: @GTITC The .14 difference is attributable to the fact that 35.63 is not actually the correct result, it is 35.625, but since you are rounding that to 2 decimal places with `.toFixed(2)`, you are gaining .005, 28 times, which equals .14 additional cents you are seeing. 997.64 is the WRONG answer, 997.50 is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bracketing issue. You're trying to multiply a string by a number in that second call to ToMoney.

```
$("#grs2").text("$" + Utils.ToMoney(((pr / 60) * g2) / 2) * wk);
```

Change to this, I think...

```
$("#grs2").text("$" + Utils.ToMoney(((pr / 60) * g2) / 2 * wk));
```

Comment: To put it another way, multiplying the return value of ToMoney() by `wk` converts the string returned to a number before the multipication.  But multiplying the parameter value by `wk` before passing to ToMoney  retains the `toFixed` string format of the returned string.

Comment: if I change it like above i get a result of $997.50, grw2 is a weekly price and grs2 is a season price so in theory I should be able to multiply grw2($35.63) * wk(28) and get grs2 = 997.64 but the result in your example above is off by 14 cents. What is happening with the .14 cents?

Answer (score 0):

so this did the trick once I found the value of weekly price grw2 I declared it as a variable. The main issue is that I was trying to find grw2(weekly) in order to use to find grs2(season). The weekly price 35.625 without getting rounded and 35.63 rounded.

the reason why I couldn't get the weekly price to match the season price is because the season price was using the pre-rounded value of 35.625 instead of 35.63 so in the formula for season I would have to have rounded up the weekly value first which I was not able to accomplish until i set it as variable.

```
var grw2 = Utils.ToMoney(pr / 60 * g2 / 2);
$("#grw2").text("$" + Utils.ToMoney(((pr / 60) * g2) / 2));
$("#grs2").text("$" + Utils.ToMoney(grw2 * wk));
```

Comment: to make both calculations in JS and C# the same I had to round the formula separate places. One time in the pr/60/g2 and finally in the result which multiplies it by the weeks. I also had to limit the amount of decimals places in C# and this is what did the trick. Basically JS and C# use different amount of decimals to round and so it was a matter of playing around with the rounding function.